# Only read the numbers in file

Tags: python, list, file, numbers

I have a problem reading numbers from a file that have word/letters, I want to skip the "word" part and only read the numbers and add them to the list.

File list.txt

```
Salad         5 1 0 0 2 1
```

This was my last attempt:

```
f =  open('text.txt', 'r')
line = f.readline(14)
print(line)

Output:
Salad
```

This is what I want to output:

```
[5, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.isnumeric()`:

```py
with open("list.txt") as input_file:
    words = input_file.readline().split()
    result = [int(word) for word in words if word.isnumeric()]
    print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[5, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can import re and use it to find the integers in the string.

The end result would be a list containing the numbers but with the string data type so I have to use a for loop to convert the items to integer data type.

```
import re
f =  open('text.txt', 'r')
line = f.readline().strip()

k = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
k = [int(i) for i in k]

print(k)
```